# How can two objects in same project have completely different paths?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dir

I have two classes, both in the same folder, both in the same project, but one has path `TutorialGame.SplashScreen` and the second one has `TutorialRPG.TitleScreen`. How is it possible that they have different root directories? (And they even extend the same class)

[image: My solution]

They are literally under each other and have different root. Just how?!
(the image is little bit wrong, it was TitleScreen and SplashScreen not SplashScreen and ScreenManager, sorry for that)

And when I let debug write the paths to the console:

[image: Console]

Comment: namespace can be different in same folder

Comment: Namespaces and folder locations don't necessarily correspond

Comment: Oh.. I though that namespace was something like packages in Java, so it would showed in the solution explorer on different places. Never mind then

Answer (score 1):

It showed up that "namespace" and actual location of the file does not have to be the same. Well, that's a new thing to learn. Thanks all for advice!